# d3.js chart flowing out of the grid

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to understand d3.js and experienced an issure related to drawing chart using d3.js. some of the data comes fine within the grid, but for some data it goes out of bound.Below is how my graph looks:

[image]

below is the js:

```
var svg = self.graph.selectAll(".series").data([data]);
svg.enter().append("svg:path");

  //hardcoded values just for this example. 
self.x = d3.time.scale()
            .range([0, 881]);
        self.y = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([0, 2), d3.round(36,2)])
            .range([210, 15]);
```

How can I set a height width to the chart in order to avoid it going from out of bound?any ideas ? Thanks!!

Comment: Set the domain such that the maximum value is higher than the maximum value in your data.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff: do you have an example to show how?

Comment: Well pretty much any example with D3 you can find, e.g. http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245

Comment: @LarsKotthoff:i'm sorry, but i still dont get what you mean by: "Set the domain such that the maximum value is higher than the maximum value". Do i need to change the {.domain([0, 2)} value to ?

Comment: how can i compute that domain value?

Comment: Did you have a look at how the domain is computed in the example?

Comment: yes..this is how my actual code looks like: {d3.scale.linear().domain([d3.round(graphing.roundDown(self.min_value, 0.1), 2), d3.round(graphing.roundUp(self.max_value, 0.1), 2)])}

Comment: You need to compute `self.max_value` in the same way as in the example.

Comment: i have computed the "self.min_value" and "self.max_value" using the d3.min feature

Comment: For the maximum, you should use `d3.max`.

Comment: this is what i used: { self.max_value = d3.max(self.flat_data, function(d) {return d[self.yKey];});}

Comment: That looks ok to me. If that doesn't work for you, you need to post a complete example that shows the error.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff: here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dkadv5ku/ Thanks for looking into this!

Comment: It's giving me a syntax error. Again, the code looks ok to me and without a complete working example that shows the problem I can't say anything further.